# Image not showing in GWT

Tags: gwt

I created a very simple test application in gwt.The image does not show when I test the project in the browser.
Here is my code:

```
public class TESTPHONEGAP implements EntryPoint {
 public void onModuleLoad() {
  RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();
  rootPanel.setSize("480", "320");

  AbsolutePanel absolutePanel = new AbsolutePanel();
  rootPanel.add(absolutePanel, 0, 0);
  absolutePanel.setSize("480", "320");

  Image image = new Image("com.mycompany.project.TESTPHONEGAP/gwt/standard/images/board.png");
  absolutePanel.add(image, 0, 0);
  image.setSize("480px", "320px");
 }
}
```

I have not used gwt since verison 1.5 but I am just now getting back into it.I have the image in the respective folder but it is just not showing.

Comment: You might wanna check out client bundles (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html) if you have to deal with images.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooted eclipse.It is working now.